# UseEffect running perfectly on first try, but fails after refreshing twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, game-development

The code  runs perfectly when refreshing once, but when refreshing twice, it resets the `money` and `luck` to 1 and 10 which are the default values. Anyone know how this can be fixed?
The first useEffect is for getting the user's data, and the second is for saving when money or luck changes.

```
const [luck, setLuck] = useState(1);
const [money, setMoney] = useState(10);
useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(`/api/email/${session?.user?.email}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "tmthisdumb123",
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      setName(data.name);
      setLuck(data.luck);
      setEmail(data.email);
      setMoney(data.money);
      if (data.rarity && data.quality && data.rarity !== "Unknown") {
        setRarity(data.rarity);
        setQuality(data.quality);
        setLevel(data.level);
        setMold(data.mold);
        setEnchant1(data.enchant1);
        setEnchant2(data.enchant2);
        setEnchant3(data.enchant3);
        setEnchantName1(data.enchantName1);
        setEnchantName2(data.enchantName2);
        setEnchantName3(data.enchantName3);
        setID(data.swordId);
        setValue(
          CalculateRarityValue(data.rarity) *
            CalculateQualityValue(data.quality) *
            CalculateMoldValue(data.mold) *
            (CalculateLevelValue(data.level) * 7.5) *
            CalculateEnchant(data.enchant1) *
            CalculateEnchant(data.enchant2) *
            CalculateEnchant(data.enchant3) *
            EnchantPower(data.enchant1) *
            EnchantPower(data.enchant2) *
            EnchantPower(data.enchant3) *
            CalculateRaritySuffix(data.rarity) *
            20
        );
        setSold(false);
        setGeneratable(true);
      }
      return { user: data };
    };
    getUser();
  }, []);
  // Save the users data everytime luck or money changes
  const saveUser = async () => {
    await fetch(`/api/email/${session?.user?.email}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "tmthisdumb123",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        luck: luck,
        money: money,
      }),
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    saveUser();
  }, [money, luck]);
```

This code is supposed to first get the user's data, then use Setters to set the money, luck, etc. Then it checks if there are changes with the money and/or luck, if so it will push them to the API, then through the database.

Comment: What do you mean by 'refresh'? Refresh of the browser page, or rerender cycle, or something else? Also, any errors in the console after that? Have you checked if on second "refresh" the fetch request is executed and the correct data received and set? Or  they were set but not rendered? So like api bug or jsx binding bug or exception during calculations, or something is wrong with async things and something was not set before something else executed that was expecting something to be set before, add a bit more details to your question

Comment: @SergeySosunov refreshing the tab of the browser (CTRL+R). And there we're no errors in the console. I've tried logging the data from the first useEffect and it's all good so there we're not issues with the API.

Comment: so you mean on first page load values are setting to correct ones after API is executed, on next reload they are reseted to defaults and not set again to the ones that you got from API?

Comment: @SergeySosunov Exactly.

Comment: Ok, just to clear that area, so if you add a console.log(data) just after the `const data = await res.json();` - how many times (and what data) it will log on first (working) page load and what will it log on reload?

Comment: @SergeySosunov, On the first (working) try, it logs the data perfectly with the correct money/luck. But on the second try, it logs the money/luck as the default values 1 and 10.

Comment: With your approach and default values - your 2nd useEffect will also be executed on page load, so it is overriding data you had in database to this default one, so current frow is send GET request, simulateously send UPDATE request, data from GET received and rendered, UPDATE request is also finished and now you have normal data in react app but in DB it is corrupted. You need to try to get rid of "default values" or to add 1 more useState like "isLoaded" which will be set to true when GET is done and in 2nd useEffect you should check if (!isLoaded) return;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments discussion: Error is due to 2 useEffects are fired on page initial render, one to get the data from `/api/email/${session?.user?.email}` and one to update/save data when `[money, luck]` changed. Due to they were both fired on first render - `getUser` returned and set values from api/db, then `saveUser` updated data with defaults from useStates and now React App has a valid data and db data is corrupted.

Solution:

1. add `const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);`
2. add `setIsLoaded(true);` just before the return `return { user: data };` from `getUser` method.
3. Modify saveUser hook to

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!isLoaded) return;
  saveUser();
}, [isLoaded, money, luck]);
```